# SpriteKit Particle Preview Not working?

Tags: sprite-kit, preview, particles

I'm having a problem with particle designing in XCode. The preview is completely blank. I read somewhere that the issue is that the particle preview DOES NOT work while running Mac on VMWare, but that doesn't explain why it's broken and how I could fix it.

So...

-Is there a way to fix this bug in VMWare?

-Are there any alternate ways of previewing particles?

-Are there any other resources that can help with particle design?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you already read that this may be the case, there may simply be no fix or workaround. It's one of the things with virtual machines, they don't work exactly like the host machine. Some glitches are unavoidable. There are several particle design tools, some work with Sprite Kit. It's  off-topic to ask for tools on SO but they're easy to find with google.

Comment: thanks. It's kind of strange how so much works, and yet the weirdest things don't. I'll go looking for some tools. Also you've answered two questions for me now, so big kudos.